# Evaluating an If condition to yield True/False

Tags: conditional, expression-test, faq

I would like to decide whether an option passed to my custom function has the value `Automatic` or something else. This is my attempt:

```
f[x_, OptionsPattern[{DataRange -> Automatic}]]:= 
    Module[{opt = OptionValue[DataRange]},{x, If[opt == Automatic, True, opt]}];
```

However,

```
f[x, DataRange -> 20]
```

produces

```
{x, If[20 == Automatic, True, opt$540]}
```

rather than the expected

```
{x, 20}
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `===` (or [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html)) instead of `==` (or [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html)) to test the condition. This is because `===` *always* returns `True` or `False`, whereas `==` can remain unevaluated. For example:

```
a === b
(* False *)

a == b
(* a == b *)
```

The fact that `==` remains unevaluated is why it is useful in `Solve`, `Reduce` and related functions, where you can write an expression such as `a x^2 + b x + c == 0`.

Now, `==` does evaluate in cases such as comparisons between numeric quantities and strings or when the objects being compared are identical. For example:

```
1 == 1
(* True *)

"abc" == "def"
(* False *)

2 == "a"
(* False *)

a == a
(* True *)
```

However, make note of the fact that comparison between machine numbers and exact numbers can give different results for `==` and `===`:

```
1 === 1.
(* False *)

1 == 1.
(* True *)
```

This is because `SameQ` tests if the two expressions are *exactly* the same, down to the representation (which they're not), whereas for `Equal` (see link to docs above):

> Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits).

Comment: `SameQ` of two finite-precision numbers also applies a tolerance; it's just less than that applied by `Equal`. So it isn't strictly correct to say that `SameQ` returns `True` if and only if the expressions are identical. (Also, one can override `SameQ`, but if you use `TrueQ` here that is no longer an issue, and the difference between `Equal` and `SameQ` is then a moot point.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. Is that not the case only for arbitrary precision numbers? If I recall, it considers them to be identical only if they're not `MachinePrecision` and differ only in the last bit.

Comment: @R.M Problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative, one could also do `If[opt == Automatic, True, opt, opt]` for cases where `==` does not evaluate

Comment: @R.M yes, that's right. I would however consider it reasonable to overload `SameQ` if different concepts of sameness are needed (which could of course give arbitrary results), whereas `TrueQ` is a binary distinction that cannot readily admit any other meanings. In this case one could equally well use the fourth argument of `If`, which is perhaps more succinct than adding `TrueQ`.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking the function you need is [`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrueQ.html):

> `TrueQ[expr]` yields `True` if `expr` is `True`, and yields `False` otherwise.

Example:

```
TrueQ[ x == Automatic ]
```

> False

Alternatively you can use [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`) but this changes the meaning of the comparison from mathematical to structural.  Frequently you want to match based on numeric rather than structural equivalence:

```
If[TrueQ[# == 0], "match", "fail"] & /@
   {0, 0., E^(I Pi/4) - (-1)^(1/4), 1, symbol}
```

> {"match", "match", "match", "fail", "fail"}

Comment: I went with SameQ because the original question was on matching Automatic in options, which is structural. This is a good addition to the general question (which was my rewording). I should've mentioned it when I made it general. Thanks for mentioning TrueQ :)