# Testing Equality Expression?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, reference-request, logic

Even if in

```
Graph[{1 -> 2}] == Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}]
```

the answer is `True` ; but why MMA doesn't show the result of the following expression?Neither `True` nor `False`.What is the reason?

```
{1 -> 2} == {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often figure this kind of thing out by looking at the `FullForm` of the expressions. In this case:

```
{FullForm[{1 -> 2}], FullForm[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}]}
```

shows that the first is a `Rule` while the second is a `DirectedEdge` and hence they are not equal. On the other hand, when embedded inside `Graph`, both sides become

```
Graph[List[1, 2], List[DirectedEdge[1, 2]]]
```

and hence are equal.

Comment: Thanks but then why it doesn't show the `False`?

Comment: It shows `True` when both sides are the same. It shows `False` when the two sides are different. To see the `False` use the triple equals: `{1 -> 2} === {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}`does indeed return `False`. It's the difference between "equals" and "identical" or `Equals` and `SameQ`.

Comment: @Alex As bill s says, `==` and `===` are different and you probably were looking for `===`. Also see: [Evaluating an If condition to yield True/False](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8798)